# How to style module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming

How to style existing module in drupal 6 for a specific view? where to place files? in the module directory or in the views dierectory. I just need to override the style of the node.
Thanks!

The second question: where do you place hook_form_alter functions? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the style of a node, the [default templates suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/190815) allow you to create a node-[type].tpl.php file in your theme directory. The [type] is the name of a specific content type you are overriding or theming. For instance, you could create a custom template for "Page" nodes in a node-page.tpl.php file. If you need more flexibility, you can create custom "suggestions". See [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions) for more details.

When creating new template files, make sure your theme already contains the base template file (see the note at the top of the [Core templates and suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/190815) page, for more detail). Also, be sure to [clear your theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176), in order for any new template files to be detected.

Views can be styled separately from the nodes they contain. Views allows for a variety of template files to be customized, depending on what level you need to customize (view as a whole, row styles, field styles, etc). For more details, click on the **Edit** tab of a view you'd like to theme, look under the **Basic Settings** section and next to **Theme**, click on *Information*.

Like other [hook functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6), implementations of [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) are placed in a .module file. If your module is called "customized" your customized_form_alter function would typically be found in a customized.module file, in a /customized folder, under /sites/all/modules.